# Mysql : finding data in last 24 hours query shows wrong results

Tags: mysql

I am executing the following query

```
SELECT post_expiredate
FROM tbl_postad
WHERE post_expiredate > DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

what I expect is, it should show the post_expiredate column with date values within last 24 hours. but it shows the wrong result

[image]

Please help me solve this issue

I tried

```
SELECT post_expiredate
FROM tbl_postad
WHERE DATE( post_expiredate ) > DATE( DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) )
```

also this

```
SELECT post_expiredate
FROM tbl_postad
WHERE post_expiredate > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY )
```

but it also shows wrong date/

Comment: @Jan Zeiseweis bro its datetime

Comment: And post_expiredate < curdate() ???
order by post_expiredate ???

Maybe these 2 will help?

Comment: Your are actually selecting all `post_expiredate`s that are **GREATER** than yesterday. You also have to exclude all that are GREATER than today.
`SELECT post_expiredate
FROM tbl_postad WHERE post_expiredate > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND post_expiredate < CURDATE()`

If you really want the rows where the `post_expiredate` is within the last 24hours, I'd use:
`SELECT post_expiredate FROM tbl_postad WHERE post_expiredate BETWEEN NOW() - interval 1 day and  now()`;

Comment: Exclude you mean @JanZeiseweis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did

```
WHERE post_expiredate > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY )
```

which is wrong and list out all dates which are greater than yesterday

**you need to find all post between yesterday and today**

```
SELECT post_expiredate
FROM tbl_postad
WHERE post_expiredate between   DATE_SUB( now( ) , INTERVAL 1  
DAY ) and now()
```

Comment: Thank you bro it works, but do you know y my query showed wrong results

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post_expiredate
FROM tbl_postad
WHERE DATE(post_expiredate) BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

this query must show all the "post_expiredate" between today and tomorrow.
Hope it helped.

Comment: I tried it and it work, my exemple show all the results between today and tomorrow. If you want to display the result between yesterday and today you replace the "+" with a "-"

Comment: Be aware that when you write your query this way (`WHERE DATE(post_expiredate) BETWEEN `) you can't use the index on the post_expiredate column, if you have one, because the internal engine hast to evaluate the DATE() function on every single row. Better use `WHERE post_expire_date BETWEEN`

Comment: Time's running backwards and so is the bride

Comment: Thank you bro it also works fine and somebody downvoted your answer and I removed it...